# environment that uses \input fails inside \tabular

Tags: tables, environments, input

I want to use the `\input{...}` command inside a new environment that is then used inside a tabular environment. The file I want to include contains `&` and `\\` to format the tabular. Everything works fine if I use a single command or the `\<EnvironmentName>\end<EnvironmentName>` makros. But `\begin{...}\end{...}` results in errors...

How? Why? I don't understand :(

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
%
%
\begin{filecontents}{in0.tex}
a
\end{filecontents}
%
\begin{filecontents}{in1.tex}
a\\
b
\end{filecontents}
%
\begin{filecontents}{in2.tex}
a & b
\end{filecontents}
%
%
\newcommand{\myinputcmd}[1]{\input{in#1}}
\newenvironment{myinputenv}[1]{\input{in#1}}{}
%
%
%
\begin{document}
%
% use command
\begin{tabular}{c}
    \myinputcmd{0} % works
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{c}
    \myinputcmd{1} % works
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \myinputcmd{2} % works
\end{tabular}
%
% use \environmen\endenvironment
\begin{tabular}{c}
    \myinputenv0\endmyinputenv  % works
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{c}
    \myinputenv1\endmyinputenv  % works
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \myinputenv2\endmyinputenv  % works
\end{tabular}
%
% use \begin{environmen}\end{environment}
\begin{tabular}{c}
    \begin{myinputenv}{0}\end{myinputenv}  % works
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{c}
    \begin{myinputenv}{1}\end{myinputenv}  % error: \begin{tabular} ended by \end{myinputenv} (and others)
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \begin{myinputenv}{2}\end{myinputenv}  % error: \begin{tabular} ended by \end{myinputenv} (and others)
\end{tabular}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: The environment form will definitely not work; is there any particular reason for adopting it? I see none, based on your examples.

Comment: First of all, I want to understand why that is happening.

Comment: An environment adds a level of grouping. If you try `\begin{tabular}{c}\begingroup a&b\endgroup\end{tabular}` you'll get the same problem.